# Value of "WL.Client.Push" is coming as undefined

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I am getting the value for `WL.Client.Push` as undefined when launching the application. Hence, the below is coming as false.

```
if(WL.Client.Push)
```

And that's the reason my push is not getting registered.

Please advise how can I define `WL.Client.Push`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This normally happens when you try to use `WL.Client.*` APIs before the SDK initialization has been completed.

The right point to start using the `WL.Client` APIs is after the flow has entered the `wlCommonInit()` method.

Do note that IBM MobileFoundation 7.x is out of support, and you should move to MobileFoundation 8.0.

You can use `MFPPush` object to invoke Push APIs.

Documentation [here](http://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/notifications/handling-push-notifications/cordova/).

A working sample can be found [here](https://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/PushNotificationsCordova).

Comment: Dear Vivin, I am using MFP 8.0 only. Can you please advise what exactly to check? I am new to MFP.

Comment: Even after trying to use WL.Client.Push after logging into the app also it is coming as undefined. When we checked the values, we have seen that WL.Client is coming and is having other sub functions(like connect, getAppProperty etc.) to that but "Push" is not there and hence WL.Client.Push is coming as undefined.

Comment: Edited answer to add more details.